# jQuery to apply css to offset (crop) displayed image

Tags: jquery, css, offset

I would like to apply css to offset the image displayed by a % that is set in the element's custom data attribute.

HTML:

```
<div class="cover">
<img src="/path_to_some_image.jpg" data-offset_y="15">
<img src="/path_to_some_image.jpg" data-offset_y="18">
<img src="/path_to_some_image.jpg" data-offset_y="24">
<img src="/path_to_some_image.jpg" data-offset_y="7">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(.cover img).load(function (offset_y) {
       var cover_w = 850;
       var cover_h = 315;
       var img_w = $(this).width ();
       var img_h = $(this).height ();
       var real_img_h = (cover_w * img_h / img_w) - cover_h;

       $(this).css ({ top: parseInt (real_img_h * offset_y / 100 * -1) + "px" });
   });
})
```

I need some guidance.

edit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".brand-cover img").load(function(offset_y) {
       var cover_w = 350;
       var cover_h = 130;
       var img_w = $(this).width ();
       var img_h = $(this).height ();
       var real_img_h = (cover_w * img_h / img_w) - cover_h;

       $(this).css ({ top: (real_img_h * $(this).data("offset_y") / 100 * -1) });
   });
})
```

Comment: sorry, i meant crop the image based the data-offset_y value.

Comment: Where is the call to cover function?

Comment: it should be called when content .cover img is loaded.

Comment: I guess you need to replace `offset_y` by `$(this).data("offset_y")`

Comment: Can you create a jFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but here the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cover").find("img").each(function () {
        var cover_w = 850;
        var cover_h = 315;
        var img_w = $(this).width();
        var img_h = $(this).height();
        var real_img_h = (cover_w * img_h / img_w) - cover_h;
        $(this).css({
             // top: parseInt(real_img_h * $(this).data("offset_y") / 100 * -1) + "px"
             // this equally does the job
             top: real_img_h * $(this).data("offset_y") / 100 * -1
        });
    });
});
```

Then make sure that the parent container `.cover` and images have a CSS *relative* position

```
.cover, .cover img {position: relative}
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

* *jsfiddle updated*

Comment: @Rick : since you are parsing an integer, you could omit `+ "px"` at the end of the `top` CSS property

Comment: thank you, great tips. Works perfectly now. Though I used .load(function(){ instead, is there a performance difference between find . each? see edited question with solution.

Comment: @Rick : you may use [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) if you are loading data from a server; are you? otherwise is overkill. `find()/each()` would be more suitable in this case.